# Problema al fusionar PDF's con PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, vscode, python-3.8

estoy haciendo un Script que une un par de pdf's , para ser identificados como dupla deben ser como "4-401.pdf" y "4-401-.pdf" , luego de fusionarlos , debe mover la dupla de Pdf's a carpeta procesados'

el problema radica cuando deseo mover los archivos originales a la carpeta procesados, con

```
ruta=shutil.move(os.path.join(current_path, Files[indice]), os.path.join(Dts_Procesado, Files[indice]))
        print('El directorio ha sido movido a', ruta)
```

los archivos se copian al archivo destino pero no se eliminan de la carpeta fuente , ademas se genera un error que lo captura el except.

no encuentro el por que se genera este error , si estoy utilizando mal el modulo PyPDF2
identifico que el problema esta relacionado con la funcion "merge" , puesto que cuando la comento, funciona correctamente la funicon shutil.move

```
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger



def merge(pdf1,pdf_2):

    current_path2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    pdfs = [os.path.join(current_path2, pdf1),os.path.join(current_path2, pdf_2)]
    nombre_archivo_salida = r"{0}\Fusionado\{1}".format(current_path2,pdf1)

    
    fusionador = PdfFileMerger()

    for pdf in pdfs:
        fusionador.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))

    with open(nombre_archivo_salida, 'wb') as salida:
        fusionador.write(salida)
        fusionador.close()


def ls(expr = '*.*'):
    return glob(expr)



current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# print("La carpeta es ...    "+current_path)

os.makedirs(r"{0}\Procesado".format(current_path), exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(r"{0}\Fusionado".format(current_path), exist_ok=True)

Dts_Procesado= r"{0}\Procesado".format(current_path)

ls_PDF1=ls(current_path + r"\*[!-].pdf")## archivos que no termianan en -.pdf
ls_PDF2=ls(current_path + r"\*-.pdf") ##archivos terminados en -.pdf
# ls=ls(r'C:\Users\PROSPERIDAD\Documents\ProgramacionAprendiendo\Python\PDFMerge\*.pdf')
# print(len(ls))
# print(ls[0])


Files=[]
Files2=[]
for ruta in ls_PDF1:
    cola,arcName= os.path.split(ruta)
    Files.append(arcName)

print("Lista 1")
print(Files)

for ruta in ls_PDF2:
    cola,arcName= os.path.split(ruta)
    Files2.append(arcName)
print("Lista 2")
print(Files2)
print("")

for pdf2 in Files2:

    sub_str = pdf2.replace("-.pdf",".pdf")
    print("Buscando >>>" +pdf2)
    
    try:
        indice = Files.index(sub_str)
        print ("se encuentra en  {}".format(indice))

        #fusionar
        merge(Files[indice],pdf2)

        #Mover a Procesados pdf's originales
        print(f"Moviendo ... {os.path.join(current_path, Files[indice])}    a -==>> "+ os.path.join(Dts_Procesado, Files[indice]))

        ruta=shutil.move(os.path.join(current_path, Files[indice]), os.path.join(Dts_Procesado, Files[indice]))
        print('El directorio ha sido movido a', ruta)


    except:
        print(f"Error no se encuentra  {pdf2}")
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te captura el except?

Comment: el tipo de error es <class 'PermissionError'> ,  cuando intenta mover el archivo , si lo copia a carpeta destino pero no lo borra

Comment: No soy experto, pero ese tipo de errores creo que aparecen cuando se intenta borrar el archivo, pero el archivo sigue abierto. No se si el with cierra el archivo automaticamente. Pero yo probaría cerrarlo con `fusionador.close()` dos lineas debajo de esto: `with open(nombre_archivo_salida, 'wb') as salida: `

Comment: Te advierto de previo que no conozco el modulo, así que no te sorprendas si ocurre un error al hacer lo que dije.

Comment: ya agregue la linea , pienso lo mismo se genera al intentar eliminar el archivo , sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

El problema recide en no cerrar bien los archivos pdf usados

se ajusto el codigo de la siguiente forma

```
from stat import S_IWRITE
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

def move_(src,dst):

    if os.path.exists(dst):
        if not os.path.samefile(src, dst):
            try:
                # print("removiendo")
                os.remove(dst)
            except PermissionError as exc:
                # print("removiendo segundo intento")
                os.chmod(dst, S_IWRITE)
                os.remove(dst)
        else:
            return " "
    return shutil.move(src,dst)
   
def merge(pdf1,pdf_2):

    current_path2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    pdfs = [os.path.join(current_path2, pdf1),os.path.join(current_path2, pdf_2)]
    nombre_archivo_salida = r"{0}\Fusionado\{1}".format(current_path2,pdf1)   
    
    fusionador = PdfFileMerger()

    for pdf in pdfs:
        # print("fusionando..."+ pdf )
        with open(pdf, 'rb') as f:
            fusionador.append(f)
            f.close()

    with open(nombre_archivo_salida, 'wb') as salida:
        fusionador.write(salida)
        fusionador.close()


def ls(expr = '*.*'):
    return glob(expr)



current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# print("La carpeta es ...    "+current_path)

os.makedirs(r"{0}\Procesado".format(current_path), exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(r"{0}\Fusionado".format(current_path), exist_ok=True)

Dts_Procesado= r"{0}\Procesado".format(current_path)

ls_PDF1=ls(current_path + r"\*[!-].pdf")## archivos que no termianan en -.pdf
ls_PDF2=ls(current_path + r"\*-.pdf") ##archivos terminados en -.pdf


Files=[]
Files2=[]
for ruta in ls_PDF1:
    cola,arcName= os.path.split(ruta)
    Files.append(arcName)

print("Lista 1")
print(Files)

for ruta in ls_PDF2:
    cola,arcName= os.path.split(ruta)
    Files2.append(arcName)
print("Lista 2")
print(Files2)
print("")

ruta=""
for pdf2 in Files2:

    sub_str = pdf2.replace("-.pdf",".pdf")
    print("Buscando >>>" +pdf2)
    
    try:
        indice = Files.index(sub_str)
        print ("se encuentra en  {}".format(indice))

        #fusionar
        merge(Files[indice],pdf2)

        #Mover a Procesados pdf's originales
        print(f"Moviendo ... {os.path.join(current_path, Files[indice])}    a -==>> ")
       

        src =os.path.join(current_path, Files[indice])
        dst =os.path.join(Dts_Procesado, Files[indice])
        ruta= move_(src,dst)


        print('Directorio ...', ruta)

        # Moviendo archivos Files2
        src =os.path.join(current_path, pdf2)
        dst =os.path.join(Dts_Procesado, pdf2)

        ruta= move_(src,dst)
    

    except:
        print("Error inesperado:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        # print(f"Error no se encuentra  {pdf2}")
```